# solve pde with BC in python

Tags: python, sympy, boundary, pde

I have this partial differential equation `ut=0`; with this boundary condition: `u(x,0)=x`
and I want to solve it with pdsolve in python

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, t # x and y are the independent variables

u = Function("u")(x, t) 
initial_condition = u0.subs(t, 0) - x 
pde = Eq((u0.diff(t), 0))
boundary_conditions = [Eq(u.subs(x, 0), x)]
solution = pdsolve(pde, u, boundary_conditions)
```

I wrote this code but then I received this error

```
typeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

How to use boundary condition to solve PDE equation

Comment: What is `u0`? See signature of `pdsolve`: does it accept boundary conditions as the 3rd argument?

Comment: You can use bc  as 3rd argument  as suggested                        
 solution = pdsolve(pde, ics={initial_condition, boundary_conditions})

Comment: Please include the complete stack trace in the question, as it contains important debugging information.